# sqlite3 database lock pops up when app is started

Tags: sqlite

i have a very terrible problem now with SQLite database. I used it for an app development and it runs well without no exception errors on my computer. but when I run the app on another pc, I get a pop-up saying SQLite database is locked..i click on it many times before the app opens and it works fine. but if I close the app and attempt to open it again, the same 'sqlite database lock exception pops up' and its very disturbing. please how do I solve this problem. thanks

Answer (score 0):

That probably means the handle for the database was not closed/disposed correctly.

You need to call `conn.close();` when the application is going to be closed, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5731893/detecting-when-a-java-application-closes)

Comment: well the funny thing is I compiled it into setup and installed it on my computer.. and when I run it, I get no errors at all. everything flows well. the problem is when I install it on another pc...the lock exception appears..@Maicin_Gordziejewski.

Comment: You have to provide the code for the database handling part of your program. Can't help without it.

Comment: I have provided the code for the database handling @Marcin_Gordziejewski.. please where did I go wrong

Comment: Changed my answer

Comment: hmm ok.. am a bit new with coding. please how do I close the conn

Comment: By using the `conn.close();` function.

Comment: i tried that already but i get this :'non static variable conn cannot be referenced from a static context'@ Marcin

Comment: conn.close(); is not working on the database handler. does this mean I should close every connection in all query statements in the app?

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static Connection connectDB(){
    try{
    String sys =System.getProperty("user.home");
    Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:"+sys+"\\Desktop\\hyper-DB\\database.sqlite3");
    return conn;
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    return null;
    } 
}
```

please the above code is for the SQLite connection.. please what haven't I done right.

Comment: When your program gets a signal that it is going to be closed, you need to close the `conn`

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to close the connection.

```
// in your code
connection.close()
```